# Total entropy less than the individual entropies

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, interactions, correlation-functions

For a classical system composed of two subsystems, is it possible to have a total entropy less than the sum of individual entropies of each subsystem

$$S(Z_1) + S(Z_2)> S_{tot}~ ?$$

Answer (score 2):

The total entropy $S_\text{tot }$ of the composite system $O$ would be just the sum of the entropies $S_1$ and $S_2$ of the individual subsystems $O_1$ and $O_2$, only if the subsystems are independent from each other. This can be rationalised very easily by considering the number of microstates. Since the subsystems are independent, the complete macrostates is defined by the pair of macrostates $(M_1, M_2)$ corresponding to the two subsystems. If the macrostates $M_1,M_2$ can be adopted by $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ number of microstates, the total number of microstates available to the composite macrostate $(M_1, M_2)$ is $\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$, because of their independence. The total entropy then comes out to be
$$S_\text{tot} = - k_B \ln (\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2) = S_1 + S_2~,$$
where $S_{1,2}$ are the entropies of the subsystems.

If we have a system where the subsystems are not independent, their macrostates would have some kind of correlation. This essentially means that at least some microstates of subsystem $O_1$ are tagged to some microstates of $O_2$. Let's say there are $\Delta \Omega$ number of these correlated microstates. Then, the number of independent microstates becomes $\Omega_1 - \Delta \Omega$ and $\Omega_2 - \Delta\Omega$. The total number of microstates of the total system can now be written as
$$\Omega_\text{corr} = (\Omega_1 - \Delta \Omega)(\Omega_2 - \Delta\Omega) + \Delta\Omega = \Omega_1 \Omega_2 - \Delta\Omega(\Omega_1 + \Omega_2 - 1) - \Delta\Omega^2~.$$
Because of the two negative terms, this number is less than $\Omega_1 \Omega_2$, and so the resulting entropy $~\ln \Omega_\text{corr}$ will be less than that coming purely from the uncorrelated part.

Comment: oh thank you very much! illuminating answer

Answer (score 1):

I think that with entropy it is insightful to consider, for any given question, both the microscopic statistical answer and the macroscopic thermodynamic answer. If the latter is available (i.e. the system is large enough for thermodynamic reasoning to be accurate) then the two should agree. (If they don't agree then either we have a counter-example to the laws of thermodynamics, which would be major (possibly Nobel-prizeworthy) scientific event, or we have an incorrect microscopic model, or we have some faulty reasoning somewhere).

If you treat an entropy statement as your preferred version of the Second Law, then the answer is immediate: entropy is by definition an additive quantity such that the entropy of a collection of independent parts is the sum of the entropies of the parts.

If you treat some other version of Second Law as your starting point, then the above can be deduced as follows. Suppose the system has parts A and B. The state of the parts is determined by some complete set of extensive quantities. We consider bringing the system to this state by starting from another state at zero entropy. To bring A to its state, starting from zero entropy, we have to supply $\Delta S_A = S_A$
where $S_A$ is the entropy of A in its final state. In principle this can be done reversibly. Similarly for B. We thus bring A and B to their final state and we have supplied $S_A + S_B$ in total, and the whole process was reversible. It follows that this is the entropy of the composite system. (The system cannot have some other entropy because entropy is a function of state, and entropy is strictly conserved in reversible processes.)